# Can not install SQL Server 2016 Basic

Tags: sql-server-2016

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2016 Basic on windows 8.1 but it keeps giving me this error.
Did it two times and every time the installation stops at the installer file "SQLServer2016SP1-FullSlipstream-x64-ENY.box" so i don't think this is a network error.
any idea what could be the problem?
NOTE: I used to have SQL Server 2012 installed but i uninstalled it completely before installing the SQL Server 2016
[image]

Comment: what does eventlog say..if there is an exception,it would log to eventvwr

Comment: @TheGameiswar there is no further exception or eventlog shown .